# Chrome extension: Removing Permission Section from manifest is not sending data from content to popup file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to submit the first version of the extension and it asks to deal with host permissions that are required so I removed the following section:

```
"permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ]
```

Uppon removing it, the `pop.js` is not fetching data in this piece of code:

```
//Fetching Data from Content Script
(async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    func: () => dataPromise,
  }).catch(() => [{}]);
  
  console.log('Result Begin')
  console.log(result)
  console.log('Result Ends')
```

When I remove `permissions block` results return `null` otherwise sends the data. Following is the piece of code in `content.js`

```
const dataPromise = chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:'send_url',msg:document.location.href}).then( result => {
.....
return {'status':resultType1,'missing':missingLinks,'found':foundLinks,'similar':similarLinks}
```

**Manifest File**

```
{
    "name": "My Ex",
    "description": "My Ext",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "all_frames": false,
            "run_at" : "document_end",
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content_scripts/jquery.js",
                "content_scripts/functions.js",
                "content_scripts/content.js"              
            ]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Agile SEO Super Cluster",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "16x16.png",
            "32": "32x32.png"
        }
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
          "resources": ["bootstrap.min.css", "index.html"],
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
      ],
    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

**Content.JS**

```
console.log('In Content Script')
console.clear()

const dataPromise = chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:'send_url',msg:document.location.href}).then( result => {
  var outLinksClean = [] //without http and www
  var uniqueDomains = []
  var pageLinksBeforeAdditional = [] // Links without count attribute which are before see additional..
  var filteredLinks = []
  var outLinks  = []
  var outLinksClusterKeywords  = []
  var outLinks_keywords  = []
  var absLink = ''
  var resultType1 = null
  var  missingLinks = null
  var foundLinks = null
  var foundHeadings = []
  var similarLinks = null

  // console.log(result) // HTML returned from remote API

  if (result.html) {
    var html = '<div id="asc_div"><div id="rendered">' + result.html + '</div></div>';
    var $html = $(html);
    var y = $html.add($('*', $html)) //Flatten the DOM

    outLinks_keywords = result.rules['link_destination']
    
    // Converting Keywords to lowercase
    outLinks_keywords = outLinks_keywords.map(function(a) { 
      a.content_cluster_keyword = a.content_cluster_keyword.toLowerCase();
      return a;
     });
    // console.clear()
    for(var url of outLinks_keywords) {
      outLinks.push(url['content_cluster_main_page_url'])
      outLinksClusterKeywords.push(url['content_cluster_keyword'])
    }
    
    for(var url of outLinks){
      url = url.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').replace('www.','')
      outLinksClean.push(url)
    }

    if(outLinks.length > 0) {
      uniqueDomains = getUniqueDomains(outLinks)
    }

    var new_dom = isolateAdditionalLinks($html.find('#rendered').children())
    var baseDomain = getDomainFromURL(document.location.href)

    var links = new_dom.find('a').each(function(index) {
      if (typeof ($(this).attr('count')) == 'undefined') {                
            if (typeof ($(this).attr('href')) != 'undefined') {
              // similar(outLinksClusterKeywords,$(this).text())
              absLink = relativeToAbsolute($(this).attr('href'),baseDomain)
              // console.log('ABS LINK = '+absLink+' - '+$(this).text())
              // pageLinksBeforeAdditional.push(absLink)
              pageLinksBeforeAdditional.push({'link':absLink,'text':$(this).text().trim()})
            }
        }            
    })
    // These are the links that are relevant to the pages. All Operations will be performed against them
    filteredLinks = filterLinks(uniqueDomains,pageLinksBeforeAdditional) 
    var validationResponse = validateType1(filteredLinks,outLinksClean)
    
    
    resultType1 = validationResponse[0]
    missingLinks = validationResponse[1]
    foundLinks = validationResponse[2]
    similarLinks = validationResponse[3]
    // console.log('Found Links')
    // console.log(foundLinks)
    // console.log('Missing Links')
    // console.log(missingLinks)
    
    // We will only go for optimization if Link Type1 is valid
    invalid_optimization1_links = []
    invalid_optimization2_headings = []
    if(resultType1) {
        // Optimization No1 for Link Type 1
        /**
         * Processing Optimization 1 of Type1.
         * Type1 Optimization 1 says that the anchor text of the valid found
         * links must be exact match or 80% similar
         */
          idx = 0
          var score = 0
          const OPTIMIZATION_COUNT_TYPE_1 = 1
          var optimization_1_score = 0
          var optimization_2_score = 0
          var valid_optimizations_1 = 0
          var valid_optimizations_2 = 0
          var optimization_1_result = false
          var optimization_2_result = false
          var NO_OF_LINKS = foundLinks.length          
          var TOTAL_OPTIMIZATIONS = NO_OF_LINKS * 1 // Since this is for a single opt only
          
          for(var foundLink of foundLinks) {            
            idx++            
            optimization_1_result = validateType1Optimization1(foundLink,outLinks_keywords)            
            
            if(idx%2==0) { // NOTE: TEMP CHECK
              optimization_1_result = false
              invalid_optimization1_links.push(foundLink)
            }

            if(optimization_1_result) { 
              valid_optimizations_1++             
            }
          }
          optimization_1_score = (valid_optimizations_1/TOTAL_OPTIMIZATIONS) * 100

          // Optimization No2 for Link Type 1
          //All Header Tags
          console.clear() // TEMP DO REMOVE IT AFTER DEBUGGING
          var headings = new_dom.find(':header').each(function(index) {
            // optimization_2_result = validateType1Optimization2(outLinksClusterKeywords,$(this).text().toLowerCase())  
            optimization_2_result = validateType1Optimization2($(this).text().toLowerCase(),outLinks_keywords)
            // console.log(`optimization_2_result for ${$(this).text().toLowerCase()}`)
            
            // Saving Headings not found on page
            if(!optimization_2_result) {
              invalid_optimization2_headings.push($(this).text().toLowerCase())
            } else {
              foundHeadings.push($(this).text().toLowerCase())
            }

            if(optimization_2_result) {
              valid_optimizations_2++
            }
          })
          console.clear() // TEMP
          console.log('outLinksClusterKeywords')
          console.log(outLinksClusterKeywords)
          console.log('Found Headings')
          console.log(foundHeadings)

          // This is being done to give suggestions for headings not on Page
          var b1 = new Set(foundHeadings);
          var notFoundHeadings = [...new Set(outLinksClusterKeywords.filter(x => !b1.has(x)))];
          console.log('REMAINING....')
          console.log(notFoundHeadings)
          
          console.log('valid_optimizations_2 = '+valid_optimizations_2)
          console.log('TOTAL_OPTIMIZATIONS = '+TOTAL_OPTIMIZATIONS)
          optimization_2_score = (valid_optimizations_2/TOTAL_OPTIMIZATIONS) * 100
          console.log('optimization_1_score = '+optimization_1_score)
          console.log('optimization_2_score = '+optimization_2_score)
          score = (optimization_1_score+optimization_2_score) / 2 // Because two optimization
          console.log('Final Score = '+score)
    }

    //Sending Message for Visual Status updatation.
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:'set_icon',msg:resultType1}, res => {});        
  }
  return {
    'status':resultType1,
    'missing':missingLinks,
    'found':foundLinks,
    'similar':similarLinks,
    'total_score':score,
    'invalid_optimization1_links':invalid_optimization1_links,
    'invalid_optimization2_headings':notFoundHeadings
  }
})
```

Comment: You've mistakenly removed permissions but you were asked to remove host permissions, which is an entirely different thing: it's a combination of `host_permissions` and `content_scripts/matches`. What was the exact message about dealing with host permissions? Do you need the content script preinjected on all URLs before the user clicks the extension?

Comment: @wOxxOm On the Publishing screen I am seeing this message: **Due to the Host Permission, your extension may require an in-depth review which will delay publishing.**

What is the reason that it is asking questions and could it be avoided? I do not think so my content script is being injected. How can I check it?

Comment: As I mentioned already, it's your content script's `matches` that triggers the warning. Currently you are pre-injecting the content script on all sites because this is what `content_scripts` declaration does. Depending on what you do in the content script, it may be unnecessary. Instead, maybe you can switch to programmatic injection using chrome.scripting.executeScript after the extension was clicked.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am using jQuery for fetching links from the HTML I am receiving from `background.js` for my work. Should I paste the content of `content.js` in the question above? Actually it also contains your code as well which you had told me while I was asking questions in recent past

Comment: Show your content.js, yes.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry I did not get a notification of your last comment. The question is updated.

Comment: Your content script changes the icon on every site depending on the page score, so if you want it to run on all sites when they load, there's nothing you need to change. You'll have to describe this in the justification field in the web store somewhere.

Comment: @wOxxOm The issue I face that the `return` data from `content_script` is always null once I remove permission. Why is that?

Comment: Like I said, there's no need to remove `permissions`, they are unrelated to the warning.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry for keep bugging you, my client is anxious about the message being displayed on the store submission page. What should I do to skip that message?

Comment: You can't skip it.